# Silex dynamic routing

Tags: php, symfony, silex

My application runs on PHP Symfony with Silex framework. The application is being tested with the following link:

```
v/prx/test/inttest/images/23464a230e641ca3929826a1548164cf/img/Tp31234564789.png
```

The app contains the following route, here:

```
v -> {v}, test -> {cmr}, inttest -> {page}, images/...png -> {path}:    
$app->get('/{v}/prx/{cmr}/{page}/{path}', array($container[ Controllers::CTRL], 'someProxyAction'));
```

However app returns an error:

```
ERROR No route found for "GET /v/prx...
```

Question is, if a route is written in a correct way.

Answer (score 0):

it is search for path v/prx/test/inttest/images but you give more then describe for the route, so router can't find this route. You should encode this string, because of slashes!

```
images/23464a230e641ca3929826a1548164cf/img/Tp31234564789.png
```

try this link

```
v/prx/test/inttest/images%2F23464a230e641ca3929826a1548164cf%2Fimg%2FTp31234564789.png
```

Comment: Is there a way to apply a route for this link? Instead of changing link itself?

Comment: I don't think so. because router just do his job and he wouldn't recognize if this parameter or path

Comment: where you build this link? can you provide a code of generation of this link?

Comment: Those are several functions, working one after another, so it is definitely not an option to change url generation.

Comment: Do you get the whole link as result of generation like

        v/prx/test/inttest/images/23464a230e641ca3929826a1548164cf/img/Tp31234564789.png

or only path like

    images/23464a230e641ca3929826a1548164cf/img/Tp31234564789.png

Comment: Last step of URI generation: $client->get('/v/prx/test/inttest'.$path, ... ) , so hardcoded location is concatenated with generated $path

Comment: then just do this
$encodedPath = '/' . ltrim(urlencode($path), '/');
$client->get('/v/prx/test/inttest'.$encodedPath, ... )
or even without ltrim if you need slash before images, and then in controller where you get this path do urldecode

Comment: Found it! I meant something like this.
->assert("path",".*")

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried doing something like that ?

> $app->get('/{v}/prx/{cmr}/{page}/{path}', array($container[
>   Controllers::CTRL], 'someProxyAction'))**->assert('path', '.*')**;

I believe that the assert should help tell the parser to accept even the / as part of the parameter